# Hull-White model with multiple times involved

Tags: fx, hullwhite, rates

Consider a pair of currencies $d, f$ (domestic and foreign, respectively) for which we use independent Hull-White models for their rates,

$$dr_d=(\theta_d-a_dr_d)dt+\sigma_ddW_d,$$
$$dr_f=(\theta_f-a_fr_f)dt+\sigma_fdW_f,$$

and define an index $S$ via the relative value of the money market accounts for each currency, an exchange rate without an independent stochastic component:

$$S(t) = S(0)\frac{B_d(t)}{B_f(t)}=S(0)\exp\left(\int_{(0,t)}dt\ (r_d(t)-r_f(t))\right).$$

With that in mind, I want to price a certain cashflow denominated in the domestic currency involving a series of convesions to and from the foreign currency. Given times $0<t_1<t'_1<\dots<t_N<t'_N<T$, I'm interested in a cashflow occuring at $T$ with an amount

$$\frac{S(t'_1)}{S(t_1)}\cdots\frac{S(t'_N)}{S(t_N)}.$$

Given the domestic risk-neutral measure $\mathbb Q^*_d$ we can price this as

$$V(t)=B_d(t)E_{\mathbb Q^*_d}\left(\frac{1}{B_d(T)}\frac{S(t'_1)}{S(t_1)}\cdots\left.\frac{S(t'_N)}{S(t_N)}\right\vert\mathcal F_t\right),$$

where some of the $S$ can be moved out of the expectation depending on the relative order of $t, t_i$ and $t'_i$. If instead we use the $T-$forward measure $\mathbb Q^T_d$ we can concern ourselves with only the index values:

$$V(t)=P_d(t,T)E_{\mathbb Q^T_d}\left(\frac{S(t'_1)}{S(t_1)}\cdots\left.\frac{S(t'_N)}{S(t_N)}\right\vert\mathcal F_t\right),$$

and would be the usual approach to price something like this. However, since the times involved are not $T$, it's not at all obvious how the calculation of this expected value would be carried out in the forward measure. Not only that, but $W_f$ is not necessarily well defined in domestic measures, only foreign measures. How can this computation be carried out? Seeing how it works for $N=1$ and having some hints for larger $N$ would be more than enough.

Comment: If $t$ is some time between $t_1$ and $t'_n$, then everything beforehand is $F_t$-measurable. Additionally, if $S(t)$ is the relative pricing of each rate, and $dW^f_t$ and $dW^d_t$ are independent brownian motions, instead of using $S(t)$, use the stochastic exponential and split up $r_f(t)$ and $r_d(t)$. Since they're independent, use the law of expectation independence. $V(t) = ...E_{Q_d^T}\left(\frac{B_d(t')}{B_d(t)}...|F_t\right)E_{Q_d^T}\left(\frac{B_f(t')}{B_f(t)}...|F_t\right)$